# OpenVPN Routes for User Defined Bridge Docker Network

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, docker

I'm setting up OpenVPN inside a Docker container so that clients are able to access other Docker containers on the same user defined bridge network. I've setup OpenVPN using [this docker image](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn) and I've changed the network from the default bridge to a user defined bridge that uses 10.10.20.0/24.

I've configured OpenVPN to use 10.10.10.0/24 with the following

```
server 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
```

I've been reading the OpenVPN documentation and have tried the following in the config to expose the Docker network to the OpenVPN client

```
### Route Configurations Below
route 10.10.20.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below 
push "route 10.10.20.0 255.255.255.0"
```

The following tests are successful:

- Client is able to connect and get an IP (ex. 10.10.10.5)
- Ping a Docker container (ex. 10.10.20.3) from a bash shell in the OpenVPN container
- Ping the OpenVPN container (ex. 10.10.20.2) from a bash shell in a Docker container

The following test fails:

- Client (ex. 10.10.10.5) ping a Docker container (ex. 10.10.20.3)

This is part of a hobby project I'm starting to learn networking and system administration so I'd like to know what I'm overlooking and what documentation I should be looking at to understand how to resolve this.

Comment: Do the containers (or their default gateway) have return route for `10.10.10.0/24` (i.e. with `10.10.20.2` as the gateway for that)? Also, is IP forwarding enabled and allowed between the tun (or are you doing tap) and the interface that leads to the other containers?

Comment: Thanks @TomYan read up more on routing and IP forwarding and was able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting up a forward route in UFW between tun and the bridge device created by docker and adding an ip route between the docker network and the openvpn network

```
ufw route allow in on tun+ out on br-xxxxxxx
ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via 10.10.20.2
```